# Raw regex string used in function as throw-away statement whose value is discarded

Tags: python

I was recently browsing the code for pycparser and saw some functions like this:

```py
def t_CPP_WS(t):
    r'\s+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")
    return t
```

How does the `r'\s+'` work? There are no function calls (e.g. `re.match`)or anything wrapped around or using it. I have very little experience with python (mostly javascript), but wouldn't this get ignored?

Comment: That line has no effect whatsoever on the execution of this function - but there are things that the module might be doing with its functions other than merely executing them.  The likely possibilities are that it's using the `ast` module to examine the contents of the function, or that it's poking around in the internals of the function object to extract its first defined constant.  (I took a quick look at the module's source, and couldn't find the relevant code.  In any case, there are clearer ways to associate a string constant with each function in a module.)

Comment: @jasonharper It's the docstring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is two-part:

1. Ordinarily in Python, you would be right: a string that is not assigned to a variable or passed to a function or method that creates some kind of side effect would not produce any overall effects. However, if the first statement in a Python function is a string literal, this string becomes the docstring of that function, [a special property that Python functions can possess](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/).
2. The provided code in that PycParser library is not pure Python, but rather uses the library PLY, which uses Python docstrings in order to define functionality [2](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html).

Thus, the provided code assigns a value to the function's docstring, and then the PLY library uses that docstring.